# Why is output not showing the Prime Numbers on the Display?

Tags: java, math, methods, primes

I've been working on this program for my introductory Java class and basically, it should prompt the user with a menu with choices whether to display the prime numbers (1-1000), mersenne prime numbers (1-10000), or fermat prime numbers (1-1000). I finally got it to run however when I choose 3 or 4 (to display mersenne or fermat), nothing shows up but the program is still running. For Mersenne Prime, it should display the numbers 3, 7, 31, 127, and 8191. For Fermat Prime, it should display the numbers 3, 5, 17, 257.

I've tried reordering the algorithm in my MyMath program, but still no output.

Here's the MyMath program for the algorithm:

```
public class MyMath
{

    public static boolean isPrime (long number)
    {
        boolean prime = true;
        int counter = 2;

        if (number <= 1)
        {
            prime = false;
        }
        else if (number == 2)
            prime = true;
        else
        {
            while (counter <= Math.sqrt(number))
            {
                if (number % counter == 0)
                    prime = false;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return prime;
    }

    public static boolean isMersennePrime (long number)
    {
        boolean mersenne = false;
        if (isPrime(number))
        {
            mersenne = true;
            while (number <= (long)(Math.pow(2, number)) - 1);
            {
                number++;
            }
        }
        return mersenne;
    }

    public static boolean isFermatPrime (long number)
    {
        boolean fermat = false;
        if (isPrime(number))
        {
            fermat = true;
            while (number <= (long)(Math.pow(2, Math.pow(2, number))) - 1);
            {
                number++;
            }
        }
        return fermat;
    }
}
```

And here's the MyMathTest Program that suppose to make call the methods from MyMath to display the numbers:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class MyMathTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        // create menu
        String menuChoice = "1: Display the Prime Numbers 1 - 1000\n" +
        "2: Display the Mersenne Prime Numbers 1 - 10,000\n" +
        "3: Display the Fermat Primes 1 - 1000\n" +
        "4: Quit\n";

        int userInput = 0;

        // begin do while loop
        do
        {
            // display menu and prompt for input
            String numberChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, menuChoice);
            userInput = Integer.parseInt(numberChoice);

            // begin switch statement for choices
            switch (userInput)
            {
                // case 1 displays prime number 1 to 1000
                case 1:
                String displayPrime = "The Prime Numbers from 1 through 1,000:\n";
                int outputLine = 1;

                for (int prime = 1; prime <= 1000; ++prime)
                {
                    if (MyMath.isPrime(prime)) // call isPrime method
                    {
                        displayPrime += String.format ("%d ", prime);

                        if (outputLine == 10)
                        {
                            displayPrime += "   \n";
                            outputLine = 0;
                        }
                        ++outputLine;
                    }
                }
                // display in dialog box
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, displayPrime);
                break;

                case 2:
                String displayMersenne = "The Mersenne Prime Numbers from 1 through 10,000:\n";

                for (int mersenne = 1; mersenne <= 10000; mersenne++)
                {
                    if (MyMath.isMersennePrime(mersenne))
                    {
                        displayMersenne += String.format ("%d ", mersenne);
                    }
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, displayMersenne);
                break;

                case 3:
                String displayFermat = "The Fermat Prime Numbers from 1 through 1,000:\n";

                for (int fermat = 1; fermat <= 1000; fermat++)
                {
                    if (MyMath.isFermatPrime(fermat))
                    {
                        displayFermat += String.format ("%d ", fermat);
                    }
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, displayFermat);
                break;

                case 4:
                break;
                default:

            } // end switch
        } while (userInput != 4);
    } // end main
} // end class MyMathTest
```

Comment: Check what the value is for `displayFermat` in the debugger throughout the execution of the problem with the 3 or 4 input values.

Comment: This would be a better question if you trimmed the code down to focus on a single input.  And you mean inputs 2 or 3, not 3 or 4.

Comment: Try deleting the ';' after `while (number <= (long)(Math.pow(2, number)) - 1);` and `while (number <= (long)(Math.pow(2, Math.pow(2, number))) - 1);`

Answer (score 1):

You have some typos in your `while`. You shouldn't have ';' between your condition and the `{` that begins the loop code.

Besides that, you mixed up your counter and the input number in the logic to calculate Mersenne and Fermat primes, so you never leave the while loop. Take for example the Mersenne condition:

```
while (number <= (long)(Math.pow(2, number)) - 1)
```

If you start with `number = 1`, you will have `1 <= 1`, which is true, you go into the loop. In the next iteration you have `number = 2`, so the loop check will be `2 <= 3`, so it will be true. If you continue like this, the second term will be larger each iteration, and you'll never exit the loop.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime):

> Mersenne prime is a prime number that is one less than a power of two. That is, it is a prime number that can be written in the form Mn = 2^n − 1 for some integer n

So, the input number has to be equal to any arbitrary power of two minus 1. For each input number, we need to start with an `exponent = 1` and increment it until the result `Math.pow(2, exponent) - 1` is equal to the input number (then we know it is a Mersenne prime) or it is greater to the input number (then we know we've gone too far, and the input is not a Mersenne prime).

In code, it would be something like this:

```
public static boolean isMersennePrime (long number)
{
    if (isPrime(number))
    {
        int exponent = 1;
        int powerMinusOne = (long)Math.pow(2, exponent) - 1;

        // Iterate until we reach the number 
        while (number > powerMinusOne){
            exponent++;
            powerMinusOne = (long)Math.pow(2, exponent) - 1;
        }

        // If we haven't gone over the number, it is a Mersenne prime
        return number == powerMinusOne;            
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You should do something similar to check whether your number is a Fermat prime.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following?

```
public static boolean isMersennePrime (long number)
{
    boolean mersenne = false;
        if (isPrime(number)) {

            int count = 2;
            while (true) {
                long check = (long) (Math.pow(2, count)) - 1;
                if (number == check) {
                    mersenne = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if (number < check)
                    break;

                count++;
            }
        }
        return mersenne;
}

public static boolean isFermatPrime(long number) {
        boolean fermat = false;
        if (isPrime(number)) {

            int count = 1;
            while (true) {
                long check = (long) (Math.pow(2, count)) + 1;
                if (number == check) {
                    fermat = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if (number < check)
                    break;

                count++;
            }
        }
        return fermat;
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain what this is doing and why?  Are you correcting a bug in OP's code, or did you just copy your working code and paste it here?  The latter isn't very helpful to OP in the long run.